# Saving a javascript files executed content to a variable in python

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt4

I have a file, "index.html" that has some javascript in it.. just a simple
    document.write("hello world"), I am trying to get the executed output of hello world into a variable in python.

Now I have been trying to get this to work and have looked throught the internet and came up with this:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *


class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()


url = 'index.html'
r = Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
print(result)
```

When I run this file though, my output is simply

```
<html><body></body></html>
```

Why is it not outputting the executed javascript?

Comment: So you want to excecute the javascript between the `<script>` tags in `index.html`?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.write("hello world");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I want to excecute the javascript between the `<script></script>` tags. First thing you can do is extract the javascript code into text with [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Then you can use [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/) to excecute this javascript code.

**Demo:**

```
from js2py import eval_js
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# open file into string
data = open('index.html').read()

# create soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

# find text between script tags 
script = soup.find('script').text.replace("document.write", "console.log")

# evaluate js code from string
result = eval_js(script)
```

**Output:**

```
'hello world'
```

**Note:** Since no javascript DOM exists without the browser, you need to `replace()` all `document.write()` calls with something else. In this case, I just replaced it with `console.log()`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm taking it that this executes anything within the script tags however I have an imported script such as `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` and then my main code script(which uses the somejs.js), `<script type="text/javascript">`. Which is why I was using the pyqt as I thought it executed the entire pages JS.

Comment: I tried executing everything between the body tags however it says somejs is not defined.

Comment: @DavidHasselhofthe2nd Hmm, I guess you can just read `somejs.js` directly? I would have to see how your `index.html` is set up for me to help any further.

Comment: This is my html file, somejs.js just contains a hash encryption. `<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="somejs.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cp = somejs("message","message2");
document.write(cp.encrypted);
document.write(cp.encrypted2);
</script>
</body>`

Comment: Tried reading direct from the somejs.js and get a navigator error, so it works but seems js2py doesn't support something.